# Is there an on-premise option for Parse analytics?

Tags: parse-platform

I am interested in using Parse analytics but I would like to host the server myself.
Is there an on-premise option for Parse analytics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to an answer I got [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/pTIDKrc1D9Y) the answer is no.